# Change cashier model from User to Hotel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-cashier

I want to use another model for cashier, not the default. I have 2 tables `User` and `Hotel` relation one-to-many (a user can have multiple hotels). I want to add possibility that a user can add different payment methods for his hotels. I removed cashier columns from `user` and I added to `hotel` table.

I put in `services.php` :

```
'stripe' => [
    'model' => \App\Models\Hotel::class,
    'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
],
```

In my controller :

```
public function get(Request $request)
{
    $creditorId = config('id');
    $user = $request->user();
    $stripeUser = $user->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
    .............

 }
```

I added in `Hotel.php` `Billable` and I removed `Billable` from User.

Now I have the error :

```
Call to undefined method App\Models\User::createOrGetStripeCustomer()
```

In the past was working for `User.php`. How can I fix this error?

`User.php` :

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements CanResetPassword {

 use Notifiable, HasSanctumTokens, HasFactory;

 protected $fillable = [
  'email',
  'password',
  'lang',
 ];
 .......
```

`Hotel.php` :

```
class Hotel extends Model
{
  use Billable, HasFactory;

  public $incrementing = false;
  protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'name',
    'user_id',
  ];
   .............
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and add your **hotel** and **user** models ?

Comment: You should get `hotelId` from request and try with `$hotel->createOrGetStripeCustomer()` since you have `Billable` trait in `Hotel` model now.

Comment: You couldn't access it from `user` model because you mentioned that you remove the `Billable`  trait from user model

Comment: What you should look for something like this `$user->hotels[0]->createOrGetStripeCustomer()` change `0` with the wanted `hotel` index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error appears because you remove the `Billable` trait from your `User` model and moved it to the `Hotel` model

so what do you need to do from the model relation in this case (`one` -> `many`)

### User Model

```php
class User extends Authenticatable implements CanResetPassword {

 use Notifiable, HasSanctumTokens, HasFactory;

 protected $fillable = [
  'email',
  'password',
  'lang',
 ];

 public function hotels()
 {
    return $this->hasMany(Hotel::class);
 }
```

after that from the controller you need to pass the `hotel` as a parameter instead of `user`

### Controller

```php
public function get(Request $request, Hotel $hotel)
{
    $stripeUser = $hotel->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
    .............
}
```